# How to create Javascript constants as properties of objects using const keyword?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, constants

How come constants cannot be set as properties of objects which are variables themselves?

```
const a  = 'constant' // all is well
// set constant property of variable object
const window.b = 'constant' // throws Exception
// OR
var App = {};  // want to be able to extend
const App.goldenRatio= 1.6180339887  // throws Exception
```

And how come constants passed by reference suddenly become variable?
EDIT: I know App won't (or rather... SHOULDN'T) be mutable; this is just an observation...

```
(function() {
    const App;
    // bunch of code
    window.com_namespace = App;
}());
window.com_namespace; // App
window.com_namespace = 'something else';
window.com_namespace; // 'something else'
```

How can a nicely organized, extensible, object-oriented, singly namespaced library containing constants be made with these limitations?

EDIT:  I believe zi42, but I just have to ask [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843809/why-is-it-impossible-to-assign-constant-properties-of-javascript-objects-using-t)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You cannot do it with constants. The only possible way to do something that behaves like you want, but is not using constants, is to define a non-writable property:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty( obj, "MY_FAKE_CONSTANT", {
  value: "MY_FAKE_CONSTANT_VALUE",
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
```

Regarding your question as to why a `const` passed to a function becomes variable, the answer is because it's passed by value and not by reference. The function is getting a new variable that has the same value as your constant.

**edit**: thanks to @pst for noting that objects literals in javascript are not actually "passed by reference", but using [call-by-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing):

> Although this term has widespread usage in the Python community, identical semantics in other languages such as Java and Visual Basic are often described as call-by-value, where the value is implied to be a reference to the object.

Comment: Aren't objects passed by reference?

Comment: Yes, but `const obj = {}` is kinda useless because the reference will be constant, but you can still modify the object.

Comment: No. Objects are *not* "passed by reference" (this is an ambiguous phrase at best). An implementation will generally "pass by *value* of the reference" but the important thing is JavaScript has [Call By Object Sharing semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). Fun fact: *the ECMAScript specification does not use the term "reference"*.

Comment: My answer still holds though because you won't be able to modify that non-writable property

Comment: @zi42 Sorry, didn't mean to hijack :-)

Comment: So const really isn't a win for us at all... unless you like to make a lot of procedural code and plop constants directly on a function's activation object.

Comment: @pst not at all, thanks for making the very important nuance. We're all here to learn.

Comment: Does anyone know why it is the way it is?  What is so wrong with using const on object props?

Comment: @pst—the term "reference" most definitely **is** used: the [reference type](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7) is a specification artifact to explain (among other things) how assignment of values works. There is even the statement "function calls are permitted to return references".

Comment: @moonDogDog—probably because object properties and environment variables are fundamentally different things. `const` is for variables, `writeable` is for object properties. Other than that, you'll need to ask the authors of ES5, there's a [community](http://www.ecmascript.org/community.php).

Comment: @RobG Whoops, my memory had blanked that out! Thanks for the correction. Note that the "reference type" in that aspect is *not* related to "passing objects", though (which is where I was fixated).

Comment: If you try to change its value, it won't change, but you won't get an error either! obj.MY_FAKE_CONSTANT = "something else"; // no error.

Answer (score 13):

```
const person = {
    name: "Nicholas"
};

// works
person.name = "Greg";



console.log(person) //Greg
```

That's why use Object.defineProperty

Answer (score 10):

There is a far simpler way to do this.  I like this pattern. Simple Objects.

```
window.Thingy = (function() {

    const staticthing = "immutable";

    function Thingy() {

        let privateStuff = "something";

        function get() {
            return privateStuff;
        }

        function set(_) {
            privateStuff = _;
        }
        return Object.freeze({
            get,
            set,
            staticthing
        });
    }

    Thingy.staticthing = staticthing;
    return Object.freeze(Thingy);
})();

let myThingy = new Thingy();

Thingy.staticthing = "fluid";

myThingy.staticthing = "fluid";

console.log(Thingy.staticthing); // "immutable"
console.log(myThingy.staticthing); // "immutable"
```

Object.freeze is doing the work here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

if you want you can leave the static property off the instance by leaving it off the object literal return on the constructor function.

const will only make it a read-only reference.  As soon as you assign it, like here in a object literal it becomes a property of the constructed object.

Answer (score 8):

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty( obj, "MY_FAKE_CONSTANT", {
  value: "MY_FAKE_CONSTANT_VALUE",
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false // instead of true
});
```

We should set also **configurable** to be ***false*** so that it will prevent the property from being deleted from the obj

```
delete obj.MY_FAKE_CONSTANT;
```

With **configurable** to be ***true***, after the line, we don't have the *MY_FAKE_CONSTANT* anymore.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor%20%22%22)

Comment: Or simply omit `configurable` entirely, since the default is `false`.

Answer (score 4):

You should not forgot that the [const declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) "creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned"

The const keyword work in a similar way than 'let', so you can redeclare it in an other block

```
const MyConst = 5;
console.log('global MyConst =', MyConst); //global MyConst = 5
if(true){
  const MyConst = 99
  console.log('in if block, MyConst =', MyConst); //in if block, MyConst = 99
}
console.log('global MyConst still 5 ?', MyConst===5); //global MyConst still 5 ? true
```

Just like @ziad-saab mantioned if you want an object property than act like a constant, you have to define it as a non-writable property.

if your constant is an object and is property should not change, use [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to make the object immutable.

```
(function(){
  var App = { };
  // create a "constant" object property for App
  Object.defineProperty(App , "fixedStuff", {
    value: Object.freeze({ prop:6 }),
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
  
  Object.defineProperty(window, "com_namespace", {
    value: App,
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
})()

com_namespace.newStuff = 'An extension';
com_namespace.fixedStuff.prop = 'new value'; // do nothing!
console.log(com_namespace.fixedStuff.prop); //6
```

Answer (score 2):

I thinks that you should define a constant in property making configurable:false and writable:false in Object.defineProperty, if you leave configurable:true then you can still making changes to the property

for example: when you set configurable:true in Object.defineProperty

```
const obj = {name: 'some name'};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  writable: false
});
```

With this you are making obj.name 'constant' but after you could do

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true // <-- you can set to true because configurable is true
});
```

But if you set configurable to false then you could never edit writable property.

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false, // <-- with this you never could edit writable property
  writable: false
});
```

And for all properties you could use Object.freeze

```
Object.freeze(obj);
```

Object.freeze will iterate over enumerable properties only