# Why is it impossible to assign constant properties of JavaScript objects using the const keyword?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, constants, variable-assignment

First, I had asked is it possible: [How to create Javascript constants as properties of objects using const keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843572/how-to-create-javascript-constants-as-properties-of-objects-using-const-keyword)

Now, I gotta ask: why?  The answer to me seems to be 'just because', but it would be so useful to do something like this:

```
var App = {};  // want to be able to extend
const App.goldenRatio= 1.6180339887  // throws Exception
```

Why can constants set on an activation object work but not when set on they are set on any other?

What sort of damage can be done if this were possible?

What is the purpose of `const`, if not to prevent a public API from being altered?

Comment: It's not that damage could be done.  Certainly many languages offer that construct.  It's that JavaScript does not offer that construct.

Comment: By what I can understand [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), `const` is not standard, even if some browsers can use it (not IE). I've never had the case where i needed this in JS anyway... You can still follow the convention of ALL UPPER CASE and most devs will understand that is a constant.

Comment: Is philosophy of language design now in scope for Stack Overflow?  There are lots of reasons why one might omit such features from a language, but I suspect in this case it's because the language was rather hurriedly rushed out the door, with as much Java-y syntax thingies attached as possible to tie the two otherwise-related languages together for marketing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer the question you meant to ask and say never use `const`.  The interpreter doesn't do anything with it.  All it does is mislead the developer into thinking s/he can assume that the value never changes, which is about as likely as if the `const` keyword weren't present.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an unchangeable value in a modern browser, use [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to create an unwritable (aka read-only) property:

```
var App = {};
Object.defineProperty(App,'goldenRatio',{value:1.6180339887});
console.log( App.goldenRatio ); // 1.6180339887
App.goldenRatio = 42;
console.log( App.goldenRatio ); // 1.6180339887
delete App.goldenRatio;         // false
console.log( App.goldenRatio ); // 1.6180339887
```

*If you don't pass `writable:true` in the options to `defineProperty` it defaults to `false`, and thus silently ignores any changes you attempt to the property. Further, if you don't pass `configurable:true` then it defaults to `false` and you may not delete the property.*

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that `const` is and not supported cross-browser (it's an ES6 feature), `const App.goldenRatio= 1.6180339887` doesn't work for the same reason `var App.goldenRatio= 1.6180339887` doesn't: you're setting an object property, so it's a syntax error to prepend it with a `var` or `const` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

var MY_CONSTANT = "some-value";
You can use conventions like ALL_CAPS to show that certain values should not be modified