# Vuex: how to define a state variable with a value that is based on the value of another state variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

In my `store` I need to have both the current week (constant) and a variable initially equal to the current week, that might get changed by mutations:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    thisWeek: moment().startOf('isoWeek'),
    currentWeek: thisWeek
  }
});
```

I get

> `thisWeek` is not defined

though How to solve this?

(bonus: is there not a way to discriminate between variables and constants in `Vuex`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your `state` with its properties  as follows :

```js
 const thatWeek= moment().startOf('isoWeek')
 
 const state= {
    thisWeek: thatWeek,
    currentWeek: thatWeek
  }
 
 const mutations = {
 }
 
 export default new Vuex.Store({
 state:state,
 mutations:mutations
});
```

assuming that you have imported the `moment` properly, but you have to know that in javascript you can't set an object property to `const` but you can keep it constant by not changing it, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843572/how-to-create-javascript-constants-as-properties-of-objects-using-const-keyword) to get more details

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a state property this way.

If all you want is to initiate both properties with the same value, why not create that value up-front, store it in a local variable, and assign it to both?

Concerning constants: a store property is always mutable. You can create constants by means of raw JavaScript (`const`) and import them, or, if you want to go full-Vuex, you probably can create a Vuex getter which returns a constant value.